# display angular UI grid and values based on the user input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I am working on angularjs application and as a newbie facing many issues. I have two angular UI grids. Based on the user input in the text fields it has to display the values in the UI grid. Having tough time to achieve this. Any suggestions would be helpful.
Please find the demo of my code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6OEFqlIivynpGf9HMv4?p=preview).

When User types/selects Atlanta in *From* text field and Chicago in *To* text field and click on *SearchLocations* button, it has to show the grid with values displayed under name AtlantaChicago. Like wise when user type NewYork and chicago it has to show gird values displayed under name NewYorkChicago. When there are no values entered in textboxes no grid should be displayed. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

HTML code:

```
  <body style="padding-left:15px" ng-controller="searchController">
    <form class="form-inline">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group" ng-controller="citiesCtrl">
            <label>From</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="places1" placeholder="Type Departure City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-controller="citiesCtrl">
            <label>To</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="places2" placeholder="Type Destination City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="SearchLocations"  ng-submit="submit()">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <h3>{{user.name}}</h3>
        <div ui-grid="{ data: user.details }" ng-show="user.show" class="myGrid"></div>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
```

js code:

```
   angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap','ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit','ui.grid.cellNav']);
         angular.module('myApp').controller('citiesCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope. places = undefined;
            $scope.items = ["Atlanta", "Chicago", "NewYork"];
            $scope.selectAction = function() {
                console.log($scope.places1);

            };
       });

   /*Controller for searchLocations button*/
        angular.module('myApp').controller('searchController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.submit = function() {
                alert("in submit");
                if ($scope.places1) {
                    alert("inside the condition");
                    /*                            $scope.list.push(this.places1);
                     $scope.places1 = '';
                     */                      }
            };
            $scope.users = [
                {'name' : 'AtlantaChicago',
                    'show' : true,
                    'details' : [
                        {"Travel Date": "10/10/2014",  commute:"Bus"},
                        {"Travel Date": "10/11/2014",  commute:"flight"}]
                },
                {'name' : 'NewYorkChicago',
                    'show' : true,
                    'details': [
                        {"Travel Date": "3/15/2016",  commute:"flight"},
                        {"Travel Date": "10/12/2016",  commute:"flight"},
                    ]
                }
            ];
            $scope.gridOptions = {
                enableFiltering: true,
                columnDefs: [
                    { name: 'Travel Date', width: '5%'},
                    { name: 'Departurecommute', enableFiltering: false, width: '12%' }
                ],
                rowHeight: 20,
                enableHorizontalScrollbar:2

            };
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `places` in parent scope - `searchController`. In this case your children (`citiesCtrl`) will inherit them and modify when model changes, so you'll be able access changed value with `submit()` call in parent. Otherwise each `citiesCtrl` will create its own `places` variable.

[Here is your updated example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IOccnZq2LLnwje7T9sxo?p=preview)